# Testing a validation attribute that depends on another property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I have created a `ValidationAttribute` that basically checks if another property has a value, and if so, the property becomes optional. Given this property has a dependency on another property, how can I mock that property properly in, I assume, the `ValidationContext`

**OptionalIfAttribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class OptionalIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    #region Constructor

    private readonly string otherPropertyName;

    public OptionalIfAttribute(string otherPropertyName)
    {
        this.otherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
    }

    #endregion

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.otherPropertyName);
        var otherPropertyValue = otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (value != null)
        {
            if (otherPropertyValue == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(this.ErrorMessage));
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
[Test]
public void Should_BeValid_WhenPropertyIsNullAndOtherPropertyIsNull()
{
    var attribute = new OptionalIfAttribute("OtherProperty");
    var result = attribute.IsValid(null);

    Assert.That(result, Is.True);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tests it without a concrete model class:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void When_BothPropertiesAreSet_SuccessResult()
    {
        var mockModel = new Mock<ISomeModel>();
        mockModel.Setup(m => m.SomeProperty).Returns("something");
        var attribute = new OptionalIfAttribute("SomeProperty");
        var context = new ValidationContext(mockModel.Object, null, null);

        var result = attribute.IsValid(string.Empty, context);

        Assert.AreEqual(ValidationResult.Success, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void When_SecondPropertyIsNotSet_ErrorResult()
    {
        const string ExpectedErrorMessage = "Whoops!";

        var mockModel = new Mock<ISomeModel>();
        mockModel.Setup(m => m.SomeProperty).Returns((string)null);
        var attribute = new OptionalIfAttribute("SomeProperty");
        attribute.ErrorMessage = ExpectedErrorMessage;
        var context = new ValidationContext(mockModel.Object, null, null);

        var result = attribute.IsValid(string.Empty, context);

        Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedErrorMessage, result.ErrorMessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing to do will be something like this,

```
[Test]
public void Should_BeValid_WhenPropertyIsNullAndOtherPropertyIsNull()
{
    var attribute = new OptionalIfAttribute("OtherProperty");
    //**********************
    var model = new testModel;//your model that you want to test the validation against
    var context = new ValidationContext(testModel, null, null);
    var result = attribute.IsValid(testModel, context);

    Assert.That(result.Count == 0, Is.True); //is valid or Count > 0 not valid 
}
```

Comment: That's testing the model and not the validation attribute though

Comment: I know but you cannot test one without the other,

Comment: Surely mocking the `ValidationContext` would make that okay.

Comment: But you intent is " have created a _ ValidationAttribute that basically checks if another property has a value, and if so, the property becomes optional."_ With mocking how would you prove that, because you get your object from - validationContext.ObjectType and validationContext.ObjectInstance. Always think about what is my test proving given ....

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below code to test my custom validator class

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsValid_Test()
{
    var modelObj = new youModelClass {
        requiredProp = value
    };
    var validatorClassObj = new yourValidatorClass();

    var validationResult = validatorClassObj.GetValidationResult( valueToValidate, new ValidationContext( modelObj ) );

    Assert.AreEqual( ValidationResult.Success, validationResult );
}
```

Excited to know if there is any other way of testing.